# Cocos2d-x how do i dispatch N node actions animation with delay between them

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Basically i want to be able to dispatch movement animation of N number of sprites
the first one is at the start the second is 10 px behind him and the third sprite 10px
behind the second. and so on .. the problem is when i loop the vector of sprites i like to animate they all move in the same time . this is what i have :

```
 Vector<Node*> OnlyCoinsContainertChildren = this->pOnlyCoinsContainer->getChildren();

    for (auto iter = OnlyCoinsContainertChildren.begin(); iter != OnlyCoinsContainertChildren.end(); ++iter) 
    {
        Sign* pCoin = static_cast<Sign*>(*iter); 
        if(pCoin->getTag() == COIN)
        {
             auto action1 = Sequence::create(
                     MoveBy::create(1.0f,vec),
                    // DelayTime::create(1.0f),
                     CallFunc::create( std::bind(&SolutionContainer::CoinsToScoreViewAnimationCallback,
                                                                                            this,
                                                                                            pCoin)),
                    RemoveSelf::create(),  
                    NULL);


             pCoin->runAction(action1);
        }
    }



void SolutionContainer::CoinsToScoreViewAnimationCallback(Node* sender)
{
    ++iCoinsToScoreCount;
    if(iNumberOfCoinsCount==iCoinsToScoreCount)
    {
        this->InnerCleanPreviousLevel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add DelayTime action with variable duration. You can use incremented counter in loop and multiply duration with it.

e.g : `DelayTime::create(1.0f * counter)`